# Firestore - Can I get all documents ID just like collection list?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I know I can get all collections ID:
[List subcollections of a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=0#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection_group)

This method only billed one document read. (If I have 1.000 Subcollections and I read collections ID list, then I pay one document read.)

> a request for a list of collection IDs, you are billed for one document read.

But I want to get all documents ID in collection.
I don't want query every documents, I'm not interest what the document contains. I need only documents ID, and I want to pay only one document read. Can be solved?

I try:

```
          return db.collection('Testcollection')
.listDocuments().then(results => {
    
    results.forEach(collection => {
        console.log('Collection ID:', collection.id);
 }); 
return;  
});
```

This is working good, but I see usage in cloud and counts every document for billing.

So I need a solution where it lists IDs of all documents but only bills one. Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  You're asking for an API that Firestore doesn't offer.  Any time any query finds a document, even if it's just getting the ID of the document, it costs 1 read per document found.